# Flex: Run scripts before/after build?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Currently I'm building my Flex projects using Flex Builder's "built in" build system (ie, "clicking the run button"), but I'd like to start running scripts before/after the build.

What's the easiest way to do that? Or, even, where should I start looking?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's possible that way, however I have heard of people using Ant inside Flex Builder to build their projects (which means you can run whatever scripts you want at whatever time in the build process), but that takes a little more work to configure. Once it's set up, it's just a matter of clicking 'Run Ant Build' instead of 'Run', so no hassles there.

Random page I found that looks helpful: [Ant in Flex tutorial](http://flex.gunua.com/?p=79)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use ant's mxmlc task, and (programatically) copy/commit the swf to wherever you need it.  For more info see Adobe's docs [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html).